# Client-Server echo program going into deadlock in UDP

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

The following is the client-side code for a UDP client-server echo program :

```
ret_val = sendmmsg(socket_id, msgs, no_of_packets, 0);
//I send message to the server
if(ret_val == -1)
  std::cerr << "Message sending failed.\n";
else{
  cout << ret_val << " messages sent\n";
  /************************************************************************/
  char buffers[no_of_packets][packet_size + 1];
  msgs = new struct mmsghdr[no_of_packets];
  iovecs = new struct iovec[no_of_packets];
  memset(msgs, 0, sizeof(msgs));
  memset(iovecs, 0, sizeof(iovecs));
  for(int i = 0;i < no_of_packets;i++){
    iovecs[i].iov_base = buffers[i];
    iovecs[i].iov_len = packet_size;
    msgs[i].msg_hdr.msg_iov = &iovecs[i];
    msgs[i].msg_hdr.msg_iovlen = 1;
  }
  //and receive the packet here, but the program hangs here
  ret_val = recvmmsg(socket_id, msgs, no_of_packets, 0, NULL);
```

My program hangs here, any idea why it's happening ? The following is the server-side code which first receives and then sends successfully, but after the server sends for the first time, my client isn't able to read it as it hangs.

```
ret_val = recvmmsg(socket_id, msgs, no_of_packets, 0, NULL);
if(ret_val < 0){
  break;
}
else{
  cout << ret_val << " messages received\n";
  for(int i = 0;i < ret_val;i++){
    buffers[i][msgs[i].msg_len] = 0;
    printf("Trip %d : %s\n", trip, buffers[i]);
  }
  /************************************************************************/
  if(connect(socket_id, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1){
    perror("connect()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  ret_val = sendmmsg(socket_id, msgs, no_of_packets, 0);
  //This send is successful, but since my client hangs,
  //the server hangs as well since the 'recvmmsg' at the top gets nothing from the client
  if(ret_val == -1)
    std::cerr << "Message sending failed.\n";
  else
    cout << ret_val << " messages sent\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in the server code looks suspicious:

```
if(connect(socket_id, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
```

What is `server_addr`?  It's certainly not the source address of any of the packets return from the prior call to `recvmmsg`.

Just remove the `connect` call.

I could write more, but is there any particular reason you are using `recvmmsg` and `sendmmsg` instead of `recvfrom` and `sendto` ?

Below is a much simpler way of implementing an echo server with a udp socket:

```
const int MAX_UDP_MESSAGE_SIZE = 65535
unsigned char message[MAX_UDP_MESSAGE_SIZE+1];
int rcvReslt, sndResult;
sockaddr_in addr = {};
socklen_t addrLength = sizeof(addr);

rcvResult = recvfrom(socket_id, message, MAX_UDP_MESSAGE_SIZE, 0, (sockaddr*)&addr, &addrLength);
if (rcvResult > 0)
{
    message[rcvResult] = 0; // null terminate the message
    printf("Trip %d : %s\n", trip, message);

    // echo back
    sndResult = sendto(socket_id, message, rcvResult, 0, (sockaddr*)&addr, addrLength);
}
else
{
    int error_code = errno;
    printf("Error: %d\n", error_code);
}
```

Comment: `server_addr` is `struct sockaddr_in server_addr`, which I use earlier in `bind` system call, and I need to do a `connect` 'cause without that, the `sendmmsg` call fails and returns -1, I'm using these calls because I need to send multiple datagrams using a single sytem call. @selbie

Comment: `sendmmsg` is not failing because you didn't call `connect`. `sendmmsg` is failing for some other reason.  Most likely because your code is not properly filling out the msg_hdr struct correctly for each reply.  (The `connect` call probably makes the lack of a valid send address a valid scenario - but all you likely are doing is sending back to yourself.)   You should print the value of `errno` when a socket function returns -1, as that will tell you the actual problem.

Comment: No socket function is returning -1 here, and why is it the case that I'm able to send only after using the `connect` call, if you see `man 2 sendmmsg`, you can see they used `connect` in the sample program given. @selbie

Comment: Jarvis, it's not common to do a `connect` on a UDP socket.  Especially on the server side where you can be receiving sockets from clients at different addresses.  I've updated my answer to provide a much simpler way to implement an echo server with a UDP socket.

Comment: The code you posted sends only 1 packet, whereas I need to send multiple at the same time. Did you see the code in `man 2 sendmmsg` ?  Why are they using `connect` there ?

Comment: In UDP, there's no such thing as sending multiple messages at the same time.  UDP datagram messages get queued on both the sender and receiver.  Your usage of recvmmsg and sendmmsg is possibly misguided. Just put the above code in a while loop and it will have the same effect as your multiple message version.

Comment: So is it okay if do `sendto` and `recvfrom` in a for loop, which is further inside the while loop ?

Comment: One more thing, I'm sending multiple packets in a for loop, and I need to calculate throughput EVERY SECOND, and store it in a file. How should I capture the throughput value _every second_, as the throughput value is obtained only after a cycle of sending packets ends ?

Comment: Based on what are you asking, and from [that other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466216/server-still-running-despite-client-stopped-sending-messages/42467106#42467106) I answered earlier for you, I suspect you think that UDP messages can be sent in batches and received in batches.  All sendmmsg does (logically) is call `sendto` in a loop.  Similarly, all recvmmsg does is look at the receive queue to see if additional messages are available.

Comment: There's no guarantee that what you pulled out of the queue with recvmmsg is the same as what you transmitted with sendmmsg.  Packets get delayed and queued on the wire.  Your recvmmsg call might only get subset of what was issued with sendmmsg.  It might contain packets from more than one address.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this sir, I just want to know how to calculate throughput every second and store in a text file ? I don't quite grasp how can I extract a value out of a program every second ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136668/discussion-between-jarvis-and-selbie).

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you're connected to the wrong target. You don't need to connect at all. `recvfrommsg()` both return the source IP:port. Just send back to the same place.

Comment: I don't understand, if I remove the `connect` system call, I'm not able to use `sendmmsg()` system call after that on the server side.

Comment: No I'm not. Since without the connect system call, the `sendmmsg` doesn't work. Check `man 2 sendmmsg`.

Comment: I will repeat. `recvfrom()` can return the source address. `sendmsg()` can be provided with a target address. The source address returned by `recvfrom()` is exactly the target address required for replying via `sendto()`. Or `recvmsg()/sendmsg()` respectively. You don't need `connect()`. See *man 2 sendmsg*.